# Construct precisely the cyclotomic extension of $\mathbf{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

I know very little about Iwasawa theory. According to what I know, the way to define the cyclotomic extension  ($\mathbf{Z}_p$-extension) $K_{cyc}$ of a number field $K$ is to notice that the Galois group of $K(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})/K$ (adding all $p$-power roots of unity) embeds into $\mathbf{Z}_p^{\ast}$ through the cyclotomic character (recall $\mathbf{Z}_p^{\ast}\simeq\mathbf{Z}/(p-1)\times \mathbf{Z}_p$ for $p>2$ and $\{\pm1\}\times \mathbf{Z}_2$ otherwise). Hence the Galois group is a product of $\mathbf{Z}_p$ with a finite subgroup. Then one can take the fixing field of that finite subgroup and this is $K_{cyc}$.

> Question:
> (1) Can we construct $K_{cyc}$ directly by telling what are the
> elements added to $K$?

> (2) Take $K=\mathbf{Q}$ for example, inside
> $\mathbf{Q}_{cyc}$ there should be a unique $\mathbf{Q}_1/\mathbf{Q}$
> whose Galois group is $\mathbf{Z}/p$ : how to write down this
> $\mathbf{Q}_1$?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez
Thank you Suárez-Álvarez! This seems not exactly what I asked（maybe it simply leads to ) as I look inside the cyclotomic extension for a fixed prime $p$ (I mean add $p$-power roots of unities). But this idea in the link is obviously inspiring!

Comment: Inspired by the comment of
Mariano Suárez-Álvarez. Actually I care base field $\mathbf{Q}_p$, notice though $\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_p)/\mathbf{Q}_p$ has dimension $\varphi(p)=p-1$ but $\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_p^n)/\mathbf{Q}_p$ is totally ramified of dimension $\varphi(p^n)=p^n-p^{n-1}=(p-1)p^{n-1}$ with $\zeta_{p^n}-1$ a uniformiser. Then $\mathbf{Q}_p((\zeta_{p^2}-1)^{p-1})$ would work by checking $p$-adic valuation as it is inside a totally ramified extension and hence itself must be one. Seems this procedure also answers my first question if I take $\cup_n\mathbf{Q}_p((\zeta_{p^n}-1)^{p-1})$.

Comment: A typo: I mean "$\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^n})/\mathbf{Q}_p$ is totally ramified of dimension $\varphi(p^n)$" in the above comment.